# passing argument 1 and 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, if-statement, char, user-input, strcmp

Hello so I've been working a little prgramme which is sort of a calculator (I'm a beginner) and well as you can see in the tittle at then end of the code, the two if strcmp doesn't work. And vscode is telling me (for the strcmp) Exception has occurred. Segmentation fault. But gcc is telling me what is in the tittle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    float num1;
    float num2;
    float anwser;

    int rnum = 1;
    int hi = 0;

    char operator;
    char ifyorn;
    char y = 'y';
    char n = 'n';

    while (hi == 0)
    {

        printf("Enter operator +, -, /, x: ");
        scanf(" %c", &operator);
        printf("Enter num %d :", rnum++);
        scanf("%f", &num1);
        printf("Enter num %d :", rnum++);
        scanf("%f", &num2);

        switch (operator)
        {
        case '+':

            anwser = num1 + num2;
            printf("Do you want to continue y/n \n");
            scanf(" %c", &ifyorn);

            break;

        case '-':

            anwser = num1 - num2;
            printf("Do you want to continue y/n \n");
            scanf(" %c", &ifyorn);

            break;

        case 'x':

            anwser = num1 * num2;
            printf("Do you want to continue y/n \n");
            scanf(" %c", &ifyorn);

            break;

        case '/':

            anwser = num1 / num2;
            printf("Do you want to continue y/n \n");
            scanf(" %c", &ifyorn);

            break;

        default:

            printf("This is not a valid character please try again :(");

            break;
        }

        if(strcmp (ifyorn, n) == 0)
        {
            printf("%f", anwser);
             hi == 1;
        }

        if(strcmp (ifyorn, y) == 0)
        {
             hi == 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do basic research. Read the [strcmp manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp), read a basic C book/tutorial, search for example code that uses `strcmp`. Then compare what you find with what you have done. Specifically look at what args `strcmp` takes versus what you have given it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `ifyorn`, `y` and `n` are declared having the type `char`.

```
char ifyorn;
char y = 'y';
char n = 'n';
```

The function `strcmp` expects arguments of the pointer type `char *` that point to strings.

So these if statements

```
if(strcmp (ifyorn, n) == 0)
```

and

```
if(strcmp (ifyorn, y) == 0)
```

are incorrect. Instead you should write

```
if ( ifyorn == n )
```

and

```
if ( ifyorn == y )
```

Also instead of assignments you are using the comparison operator in these statements

```
 hi == 1;
```

and

```
 hi == 0;
```

You need to write

```
 hi = 1;
```

and

```
 hi = 0;
```

Increasing the variable `rnum` looks senseless

```
    printf("Enter num %d :", rnum++);
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter num %d :", rnum++);
    scanf("%f", &num2);
```

Why not just to write

```
    printf("Enter num %d :", 1 );
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter num %d :", 2 );
    scanf("%f", &num2);
```

And in the code snippet under the label `default` you should add one more statement

```
    default:

        printf("This is not a valid character please try again :(");
        ifyorn = y;
        break;
```

Comment: One last question, do I need to delete the post when the question is answered and Vlad have a good day man

Comment: @Vaxaop No, the question should be kept. And moreover you will lose the upvoting I made for your question.:)

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to be mean to the guy ,he is learning.

You are getting this error because you are passing characters to strcmp() instead of pointers to characters.

Here is more information regarding that function.

> https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcmp